# Laravel 4 controller file name change causing include error

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4

I recently deployed a Laravel 4 project on the Web after extensive testing locally, no issues offline but several weird ones after it became live.

The project has a Git repository and one controller would occasionally not be noticed by my IDE (PHPStorm) as being changed in the repository - I would make changes, attempt to commit, and it would show an error saying that there were no changes. Also, at one point the file was somehow renamed to "news.php" from "News.php." I fixed the case of the file back to the uppercase N I did not rename anything else in the project - all references to this class (and therefor file) remained "News."

Out of the blue this morning, a route using the News controller resulted in a 500 error stating that it could not include the file in question. I checked the FTP file system and verified that the file was present and intact, nothing appeared wrong with it at all. After much frustration, I renamed the file to "news.php" (lowercase) and everything worked again. I attempted to rename it to "News.php" again and the 500 error returned.

Another odd thing that happened was that a reference to a controller action was all lowercase (oversight on my part?) and randomly the app crashed with a 500 error Class Not Found. I tested the app locally and it worked fine with either lowercase or uppercase, renaming the controller reference to "Admin_News" from "admin_news" solved the problem on the production server.

Does Laravel 4 have some sort of a cache that might be referencing "news.php" and refusing to use "News.php?" Any ideas on this weird behavior?

Comment: Check out app/storage/compiled.php, which might be the source of your woes. Also, what type of computer are you on? Is the file system case-insensitive?

Comment: The project was produced by yours truly on Windows, Mac, and Linux. Whatever was around at the time. Good suggestion on compiled, I will check when I start in the morning.

Comment: I just checked and I do not have an `app/storage/compiled.php` - is this normally present in Laravel 4? And not sure if it would matter in this case but I am using rtablada package-installer, https://github.com/rtablada/package-installer

Comment: Laravel does create that file when composer is used to install/update (Check out composer.json to see commands run on update - `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize`). I'm not sure if they work on windows without a PHP executable available in any case, so `compiled.php` might just not exist for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when changing routes or controllers, try

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and it will rebuild the autoloader with new names/content

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! Happened again out of the blue.. you saved the day

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to mind when I read your question is are you developing on a windows computer and deploying on a linux server (or the other way around?)

I had a similar issue on my set up, I develop on a windows machine at work and we deploy to a linux server. The file-system on windows appears to be insensitive to case so news.php = News.php whereas the linux file-system is case sensitive. This also appears to be the case with namespace names. /App/Models/Auth = /App/models/Auth on windows but not linux. This cause a few headaches before I figured it out.

I have now begun using Vagrant to set up a local development area that is a mirror image of the system I am deploying to meaning if it works on one it will work on another.

Comment: Good suggestion. I push everything to BitBucket and then pull it to whatever machine I am using - I code on a Mac at home, Windows or Linux laptop on the road. I use PHPStorm in all cases. The web host is indeed Linux based.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to check the Laravel IDE Helper generator for PHP storm. You can get it from github: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper I guess you are having problems with PHP Storm's refactoring feature updating some parts of your code without asking. Anyway, the generator will help you identify many of those problems from inside PHP storm and ease the whole development process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, have been using the helper for a long time, love it. Forgot about the refactoring, good thought.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a way to access to Models and Controllers. I always name the files like the name given to the class (e.g. if class was named as BaseController, the file must be named as BaseController.php). But maybe the usage of PHP Storm is doing an action out of control of the framework.